A kind of generalized eigenvalue problem
Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ denote three complex $2 \times 2$ matrices. Find necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$, $B$ and $C$ for the existence of a nonzero $v \in \mathbb{C}^2$ such that

$Av$, $Bv$ and $Cv$ are all nonzero, and
$Av$, $Bv$ and $Cv$ are all multiples of each other.

Motivation: I was playing around with a problem and was led to formulate the problem above. Well, actually, I am trying to prove a statement by contradiction. I assumed the statement was false, and then was able to show that it would imply the existence of a $v$ such as above for some specific $A$, $B$ and $C$. This led me to ask the question above, which is a kind of generalized eigenvalue problem, and can be formulated independently.
Edit: I am thinking that the problem can be reformulated as to whether or not some rational cubic curve in $\mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$ intersects non-trivially the "standard" twisted cubic.
Indeed, consider the map $\gamma$ from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\operatorname{Sym}^3(\mathbb{C}^2)$ which is defined by
$$ \gamma(v) = Av \odot Bv \odot Cv. $$
This induces a cubic rational map $\tilde{\gamma}$ from $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$. I think that the image of this map can be written as an intersection of quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$, but I am not entirely sure.
On the other hand, the twisted cubic is (up to some binomial coefficients) induced by the map
$$ v \mapsto v \odot v \odot v.$$
And the image of the twisted cubic in $\mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$ is known to be the vanishing locus of an ideal which is generated by $4$ quadrics (it is not a complete intersection).
So the problem is equivalent to whether or not the image of $\tilde{\gamma}$ intersects non-trivially the image of the twisted cubic. So I think it amounts to whether or not the common vanishing locus of finitely many quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$ is non-empty.
Also note that a similar question was asked before here, see @Theo Bendit's comment below. There is an answer in the linked post but I am hoping to get an alternative solution which is more algebro-geometric.

Similar question

Here is an answer of sorts. First of all, none of the matrices $A, B, C$ can be zero. If all three matrices have rank 1, then the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of $v$ is that all three matrices have the same range. Suppose that the matrix $C$ is invertible. Then the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of $v$ is that the matrices $C^{-1}A, C^{-1}B$ have a common eigenvector with nonzero eigenvalue.
In the case when $A, B, C$ are all invertible, the equivalent condition is
$$
Tr [C^{-1}A, C^{-1}B]=2. 
$$
(The latter equivalence is not entirely obvious.)
Edit. This is a good linear algebra exercise: Two invertible 2x2 complex matrices $X, Y$ have a common eigenvector if and only if $Tr[X,Y]=2$. Here $[X,Y]=XYX^{-1}Y^{-1}$. See Theorem 4.3.5(i) in
Beardon, Alan F., The geometry of discrete groups, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 91. New York - Heidelberg - Berlin: Springer-Verlag. XII, 337 p. DM 108.00;  (1983). ZBL0528.30001.
If, additionally, we assume that $X, Y\in SL(2,\mathbb C)$ then the condition $Tr[X,Y]=2$ is equivalent to the condition
$$
\det (XY -YX)=0,
$$
see Exercise 4.3(4) in the same book.

Thank you Moishe. Yes, I understand, but I was kind of hoping for a more algebro-geometric approach, along the lines of my new edit (new at the time of writing).

@Malkoun: OK, good luck with that.

The equivalent condition looks interesting! Is that the trace of a commutator on the LHS please?

@Malkoun: Yes, of course, the multiplicative commutator.

@Malkoun: The multiplicative commutator means $[X,Y]=XYX^{-1}Y^{-1}$.

I have to tell you. You are right. It is not obvious!

@Malkoun: What details do you find unclear?

I got that $XY - YX$ has $0$ as eigenvalue of multiplicity 2... Something still doesn't make sense to me...

Take $X$ and $Y$ to be the 2 by 2 identity matrix. Of course their Lie algebra commutator vanishes...

@Malkoun Oops, I did not copy the formula correctly.

For the non-obvious direction, if you assume that the group-level commutator has trace equal to $2$,, then I can show that the Lie algebra-level commutator has eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $2$. But I still did not yet prove that $X$ and $Y$ must have a common eigenvector. Maybe I am missing something obvious...

You can look it up in Beardon's book, or I can write a proof, it is essentially a brute-force computation. @Malkoun

After you told me it was a brute force computation, I managed to do it, basically by considering $X$ to be in a Jordan canonical form. It was not that bad indeed. We just see that in all cases, there is a common eigenvector. Ok good!

@Malkoun: Right.
